# How to grant access to read/write files on a sharepoint site via OAuth2

Tags: sharepoint, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am having trouble figuring out how to give an application read/write access to a sharepoint site.

Here's what I've done:

1. I made a sharepoint site
2. I created a microsoft azure application and authenticated users using OAuth2
3. I set delegated permissions on the app control panel to include Files.ReadWrite.All
4. I created a user who has read/write permissions to the sharepoint site and authenticated him with the app.
5. I have a program (in PHP) which has valid access_token and refresh_token, but when I try to upload files, I get a 403 error.

```
Client error: `PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!XxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxB/items/root:/StationMD%20Addl%20Enrollees%2020200508.xlsx:/content` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "accessDenied",
    "message": "Access denied",
    "innerError": {
```

Oddly enough, I was able to do this as the user who created the site, but not as a dummy user (who also has permission to read and write files)

So...

The problem seems to be app permissions. Is there a way to set application permissions for just that sharepoint site, or is Files.ReadWrite.All my only option? Can I use delegated permissions for a user who is not currently logged in, but did authenticate via OAuth2?

---

Some more information 5/16/20

I have two users. One is my regular account which I used to create the Sharepoint Site. The other is a "service account" used to upload files. Both users are able to edit/upload/delete files using the GUI. However, when using the API, the service user can't upload files, while the regular user can. I made sure that both users were members of the site. Using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I am able to see the drive.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!XXXXxxxxx
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives/$entity",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-04-26T11:19:17Z",
    "description": "",
    "id": "b!XXXXXxxxxx",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-05-16T11:56:23Z",
    "name": "Documents",
    "webUrl": "https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sftp/Shared%20Documents",
    "driveType": "documentLibrary",
    "createdBy": {
        "user": {
            "displayName": "System Account"
        }
    },
    "owner": {
        "group": {
            "email": "xxxx@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
            "id": "xxxxx-xx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
            "displayName": "sftp Owners"
        }
    },
    "quota": {
        "deleted": 2812850,
        "remaining": 27487773843447,
        "state": "normal",
        "total": 27487790694400,
        "used": 8848121
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite a while since I worked with SharePoint, but I'll try to answer for the Azure AD related questions.

> Oddly enough, I was able to do this as the user who created the site, but not as a dummy user (who also has permission to read and write files)

This is pretty odd. I would expect the call to work with the permissions the app has :\

> Is there a way to set application permissions for just that sharepoint site, or is Files.ReadWrite.All my only option?

This one I am not sure about.
You can either give the app the delegated permission Files.ReadWrite.All which allows you to access/modify any file the user can, or you can give the application permission Files.ReadWrite.All which allows the app to access/modify any file in any site collection.

> Can I use delegated permissions for a user who is not currently logged in, but did authenticate via OAuth2?

Short answer, yes.
If they authenticated at least once to your app, you got a refresh token for that user when they did.
Store that refresh token securely, and use it to get a new access token when needed.
Do note a couple things:

- The refresh token itself will expire after some time (maybe 2 weeks?)

  - When you get a new token with that refresh token, you also get a new refresh token
- Token refresh can fail due to some factors, your app should be ready for this

  - The user will have to authenticate again to provide a new refresh token

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge:

Can't limit to specific site in app permission level(limit in logic if need).

Use Application permission if want to skip user to log in.

Use permission in Microsoft Graph to access data in SharePoint if want to use graph api.

[image]